# Oauth 2.0 Android use Spring-For-Android

Tags: android, spring, oauth-2.0

I developed an android application and I use the Spring libs for Android.
I started by to make a simple authentication login/password using a spring-android-rest-template.
Now I have to use "spring-for-android" libs to authentication via the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

my question is to search a small application that demonstrates the use, not that of Facebook, Google, Twitter.
I used a Spring Server to communicate with my Android app.

Answer (score -1):

Example with OAuth2 and spring for android 
http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/android-oauth2-rest-client-with-spring.html 
but I use scribe to OAuth 2.0 authentication.